# ImportError while deploying Django app to heroku

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to deploy my Django app to heroku.

**What is the problem ?**

After uploading my app to heroku. I try to access it but I get an `Application Error` which also mentions this command `heroku logs --tail` to get the details of the error. So I run the command and I get a log with the following details (It shows a lot of content in the log but I have shown only a few):

```
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139298+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-08-27 20:03:18 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139347+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139351+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139356+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139358+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139360+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139361+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139363+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139365+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139366+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139368+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139370+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139371+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139373+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139375+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139377+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139379+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/ditook/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139380+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139382+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139384+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139385+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139387+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139388+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139390+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139391+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139393+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139394+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139396+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(name)
2018-08-27T20:03:18.139397+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named django_visitor_information
```

Everywhere in the log I see `ImportError: No module named django_visitor_information` mentioned.

***settings.py:***

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Authentication.apps.AuthenticationConfig',
    'django_visitor_information',
    ...,]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',        
    'Authentication.timezone_middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
    ...,]

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'                    
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'    
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'    
USE_I18N = True    
USE_L10N = True    
USE_TZ = True

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')    
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media/Img')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
```

**project structure:**

```
- myproject
  - myproject
    - migrations
    - _init_.py
    - admin.py
    - models.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py
    - wsgi.py
  - static
  - templates
  - db.sqlite3
  - GeolP.dat // this is used by django_visitor_information
  - manage.py
  - Procfile
  - requirements.txt
  - runtime.txt
```

I also tried to set `init.py` of `django_visitor_information` app to empty. Because I saw it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985695/error-while-deploying-django-app-to-heroku) post. But that still didn't helped.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an app called `django_visitor_information`? Where is it in relation to the rest of your code? Show your project structure.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah I do have a `django_visitor_information` and yes its relation to the rest of my code. And I edited my question with `projects structure` check it out.

Comment: So is django_visitor_information a third party app? Have you included it in requirements.txt?

Comment: Yes its a third party app. No I haven't included it in requirements. How should I include it in requirements ?

Comment: How are you expecting it to be installed of you haven't put it in the requirements? How is Heroku supposed to know to install it? You need to list it there just like all the other libraries, such as Django itself.